# Multiple Frontends using Istio Ingress and Route Rules

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-ingress

Is it possible to do the traffic routing using the route rules as described in the image below? The traffic routing would need to happen right after the traffic enters the cluster.

[image]

We have been fiddling around with them but always hit a wall as soon as we had two route rules and used a uri regex in one of the rules.

Our idea is to configure the istio ingress like so

```
# Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: frontend
    servicePort: 8080
```

And then configure the route rules that split the traffic depending on the uri header. Here is an example of how we would configure the products route rule:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: products-rule
spec:
  destination:
    name: frontend
  precedence: 2
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        uri:
          regex: "^/(?:.*?)/?products(?:/.*)?$"
  route:
  - labels:
      fe-app: products
```

Is this setup possible with istio?

Comment: It is possible to combine `istio-ingress` with `route-rule`. Is there any problem you are facing with this configuration? Looks valid to my.

Comment: One problem is that the uri regex route roule doesn't work. I could only get a prefix uri rule to work, which doesn't solve our problem of having the project key url parameter before that sadly.

Comment: What is the URI that you are trying in the browser and what is the result? You can also take a look at the ingress pod logs

Comment: When I go to /foo/products I get a 404.
[2018-03-09T15:38:02.936Z] "GET /foo/products HTTP/1.1" 404 ...

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It seems Kubernetes Ingress does not support regular expressions, see https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1360. **So the answer below would not work.**

I would create three different services: `products`, `settings` and `customers` and use Kubernetes Ingress [fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout). I would use your regex expressions for the paths. I would try it first with a plain Kubernetes Ingress, without `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"` annotation. If it would work, I would add the Istio annotation and verify that it works as Istio Ingress as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's also an option we have been thinking about but we couldn't find any documentation on using regex path rules.

Comment: Hmm, I searched for it and it is possible it does not work - here is an issue open https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1360 against Kubernetes. I need to check what happens with Istio Ingress.

Comment: It seems regular expressions do not work for Ingress, will update the answer.